# android studio gradle build apk

Tags: android, gradle, applovin

```
(Error:(17, 2) error: package com.applovin.adview does not exist
Error:(18, 24) error: package com.applovin.sdk does not exist
Error:(19, 24) error: package com.applovin.sdk does not exist
Error:(20, 24) error: package com.applovin.sdk does not exist
Error:(21, 24) error: package com.applovin.sdk does not exist
Error:(22, 24) error: package com.applovin.sdk does not exist
Error:(23, 24) error: package com.applovin.sdk does not exist
Error:(24, 27) error: package com.applovin.adview does not exist
Error:(34, 20) error: cannot find symbol class AppLovinAdView
Error:(35, 20) error: cannot find symbol class AppLovinSdk
Error:(46, 58) error: cannot find symbol class AppLovinAdLoadListener
Error:(46, 81) error: cannot find symbol class AppLovinAdDisplayListener
Error:(50, 27) error: cannot find symbol class AppLovinAd
Error:(55, 24) error: cannot find symbol class AppLovinAd
Error:(67, 26) error: cannot find symbol class AppLovinAd
Error:(49, 6) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(54, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(66, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(93, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(135, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable AppLovinSdk
Error:(176, 96) error: cannot find symbol variable AppLovinAdSize
Error:(176, 129) error: cannot find symbol class AppLovinAdLoadListener
Error:(176, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable AppLovinSdk)
```

Using Android Studio I get this error when I try create an APK of buildbox game. Any help is appreciated.

screenshot of error:

[image]

Comment: seems that apploving library u havent imported properly and android not able to recognize it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following dependencies in your build.gradle file of your app.

```
compile project(":AppLovin-SdkJar")
compile project(":AppLovin-Android-NativeAdCarousel")
```

Also, make sure to check this page where there are several examples and guides on how to properly install AppLovin SDK:

https://github.com/AppLovin/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the AppLovin library isn't being recognized by your project.  We have the SDK in JCenter now.  You should be able to add the following 'compile' line to your app-level build.gradle file in the 'dependencies' section in order to add our latest SDK to your project:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:7.3.2'  <-- add this line
    ...
}
```

You can also send us an email at support@applovin.com if you have any questions.

Comment: thnk u ...but now the same prblm is occurng with chartbosst

Comment: Error:(11, 26) error: package com.chartboost.sdk does not exist
       (here the error code is)

Comment: You will need to consult Chartboost's documentation on how to properly integrate their SDK on Android.

Comment: You should target the latest version on JCenter - `compile 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:+'`